# Make a exclusion list + files list using winrar command line

Tags: batch-file, zip, compression, rar, winrar

I made this script below to make a backup of some files. It works fine, but i wanted make a list for the files that need be skipped from compressing.

For example:

my `list.txt` has all the files that will be compressed. But i wanted to make another list for the files that need be skipped, like `exclusion_list.txt`. Actually i put all files that i want be ignored from compressing into the command line, as shown below `-x*\Test1 -x*\Test2`.
But i really wanted to make a exclusion list for not keep changing the command line everytime i need to exclude a file or folder.

How i can do it?

```
"%winrar%\winrar.exe" a -x*\Test1 -x*\Test2 -ibck -ep1 -ilog%userprofile%\Desktop\log.log "compressed %date:/=.%.rar" "@list.txt"
```

Comment: @BlackMamba `"compressed %date:/=.%.rar"` is really not good. Open help of __WinRAR__ by starting __WinRAR__ and clicking in last menu __Help__ on first menu item __Help topics__. Select first tab __Contents__, expand list item __Command line mode__, expand list item __Switches__ and click on __Alphabetic switches list__. Read this list from top to bottom and click on switch `-ag[format]` to read help for this switch. `-agYYYY-MM-DD` and `"compressed .rar"` or better `"compressed_.rar"` would be definitely better because of being Windows region setting independent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://documentation.help/WinRAR/HELPCommandLineSyntax.htm): the exclusion option `-x` also supports a list file when it is preceded by `@`:

```cmd
"%winrar%\winrar.exe" a -x@exclusion_list.txt -ibck -ep1 -ilog%userprofile%\Desktop\log.log "compressed %date:/=.%.rar" "@list.txt"
```

with the file `exclusion_list.txt` containing:

> ```cmd
> *\Test1
> *\Test2
> ```

By the way, there is even a [console version](https://documentation.help/WinRAR/HELPConsoleRAR.htm) of WinRAR, called `rar.exe`, which is a non-GUI version.